# Home Page Layout Assignment in profiles metadata

Tags: home-page-layout

I'm create 2 differentd home page layouts to different prifiles ( Setup->Customize->Home->Home Page Layouts (button 'Page Layout Assignment')).
How can I change Home Page Layout Assignment in profile metadata file (for exem. 'Admin.profile')?

Comment: What are you trying to do? you can instead set the page layout on different profiles and export the profile using force.com migration tool(ant) ?

Comment: This is not 'page layaut' this is 'Home Page Layout'  Setup->Customize->Home->Home Page Layouts  (button 'Page Layout Assignment')